# Friend's OneDrive for Business appearing on my Mac Word

Tags: mac, microsoft-office, onedrive

A friend logged into her OneDrive for Business account from my Mac some time ago, and now her files are all appearing as "Recent" in my Mac Office apps (Word 16.53, Excel 16.53). Moreover, I can open and edit them even though I am not logged in as her anywhere I can find.

I suspect this is very similar to [Clear cached Microsoft Live account credentials in Office apps](https://superuser.com/questions/1361713/clear-cached-microsoft-live-account-credentials-in-office-apps), however that question is for Windows and I am on a Mac.

[image: Word 16.53 Recent Files dialog showing files from my friend's OneDrive for Business account]

If I attempt to sign out of Word for Mac, I am asked to sign out of my personal Office account, not her business account:
[image: Word 16.52 Sign Out dialog showing my personal account information]

Note that when I access my personal account from office.com I do not see her business files as recent:

[image: Screenshot of Office.com from my personal account showing none of my friend's business files]

Things I have attempted:

- Standard signing out and signing back in from the Word app
- Standard uninstall / reinstall of Office apps
- Standard drag-to-trash / reinstall of the OneDrive app
- Uninstalling and removing Library files [as recommended here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-for-mac-eefa1199-5b58-43af-8a3d-b73dc1a8cae3)
- Removing Keychain entries with 'adal' and 'Microsoft' and 'Office' and 'OneDrive' and restarting [as recommended here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/sign-In/sign-in-to-office-2016-for-mac-fail?WT.mc_id=365AdminCSH_SocContactUs)

Comment: Might be one for https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Microsoft support, it appears that the answer can be found here: [How to remove Office license files on a Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-remove-office-license-files-on-a-mac-b032c0f6-a431-4dad-83a9-6b727c03b193), using the License Removal Tool.

After running it, the access to the OneDrive for Business went away, and I just needed to do a simple re-log-in on my personal account to be back up-to-speed.